# Bigcommerce - Side Cart Total always shows $29.00

Tags: bigcommerce

I am having some issues with a BigCommerce theme. It is an exact copy of a working theme, but on the new site, the mini basket/cart always shows $29.00 no matter what is in the cart (site is also set up to use £)

The issue lies with %%LNG_SideCartTotalCost%%.

Whats odd is that I checked the language file (via the url) and the text for this variable should be:

```
"Your sub total is <strong>%s</strong>."
```

Yet its coming through as:

```
"Total: <strong>%s</strong>."
```

I'm unsure who this was changed (the site is a clients, who has had work done by other developers)

How would someone change this language variable in BigCommerce? I was under the impression you could only edit themes, and not code?

So, any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is was an issue with the language file. The support staff had to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Bigcommerce. The file you will need to edit is the sidecartcontents.html file. You are able to customize HTML, CSS, Javascript and JQuery. The only thing you don't have access to is any global variables that require PHP files. As a SaaS platform, we don't provide our clients access to the PHP files.